# Flatten matrix in Maxima

Tags: maxima

How to flatten a matrix composed of other matrices in Maxima?

What I mean by this is, if I put a matrix to be an element in a new matrix, I cannot reach the underlying elements directly. The dimension of the outer matrix does not change!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the function `mat_unblocker`.